# How execute the pool in multiprocessing with out using (if __name__ == '__main__') main function

Tags: python

```
def fun:
    path = "C:\\Users\\siya\\Desktop\\data"
    if filesnames.endswith('.xlsm'):
        file_path = Path(os.path.join(path, filesnames))
        sheet = pd.read_excel(file_path, 'sheetname', index_col=False)
        print(sheet)
def func_process:
        with Pool(processes=12) as pool:
            filesnames = os.listdir(path)
            pool.map(fun, filesnames)
func_process()
```

getting an error when i try use the pool in func_process instead of

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

can any one help how execute the pool with out using main function

Comment: This sounds like the old joke: "Doctor it hurts when I do ..."

Comment: What error do you get? Is this code a [mcve]? Please see [ask].

Comment: If you don't have a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, then there is simply no way to use `multiprocessing` in a way that actually works under all circumstances.  *Why* do you want to avoid this?  Note that in your example, only the actual call to `func_process()` needs to be inside the block, it does no harm to have the function definition outside as long as only the main process calls it.